# Importing 40,000 Customers into Magento

Tags: magento, import

I'm trying to import a large (40,000) customer base from .csv into Magento and it's taking an age to do it.

I was wondering if there is a quicker way to import customers into the system or use a third party app?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I had to deal with the same goal as you: importing more than 40k customers into my Magento.

After several tests with native CSV import solution and 3rd party tools, I've achieve this goal with developing a Magento shell script on my own.

This is the solution I would recommend you to use (if you have development skills or a technical people that can help you).
This is a better/cleaner & faster processing approach to ensure your data are correctly stored.

EDIT: I would precise that customer import process should take care of Magento good practice: don't insert directly with RAW sql statements but use Magento API to do your insert.

Did you had a look at the well referenced below topic?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60003/import-csv-file-through-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

Several days ago, I imported all customer from my old site to new magento site.

My requirements was to import customer from one magento site to another magento site.

So, i export mysql tables (start with customer_) from old site and Import it to the new magento site.

Thus, all customer from old site is transferred to my new magento.

If you have same requirements then its very easy to do.

Thanks